# How to get rid of short and useless reviews on Steam?

Tags: steam

Steam reviews section is progressively plagued with more and more short and absolutely garbage "reviews". Sometimes they are funny, sometimes not but they give next to zero information about should I try this game or not and why.

Here are some examples copypasted directly from few games:

> This Game Good. Big Tank go boom.
>  CoH3 when?
>  Thanks,
> HumbleBundle.
>  It's good unless I lose, then it's bad
>  I'm
> playing with a Joystick!
>  Great game.... Wish there was COH3
> (empty review - literally empty text box, has 153 helpful votes)
> it fun and tiddies
>  im a lesbian
>  Anime
>  Yes
>  buying the
> game coz hololive member

Yes, each line above is a complete text of an entire "review". Just voting "not helpful" doesn't seem to solve the problem - for some reasons people tend to massively vote "helpful" for this junk. Each one-line "review" above was pulled from the top of list sorted by "most helpful".

I feel that size would be good criteria to get rid of those reviews - it is pretty logical that you'd have to write at least some length of text to make a really useful review. So, is there some way to filter those short reviews out? Preferably both on game page and in on full review list browse page (`/app/NNNN/reviews/` URLs).

Comment: On the other hand, filtering reviews that are too short may stop you from seeing helpful "Game doesn't launch" or "Crashes on startup" reviews.

Comment: What would be long enough to mark it as a potential helpfull review? 'I spent 600 hours and lost my progress', is already a bit longer (and very usefull i.m.o) but still way shorter than the full poetry we sometimes see where you have to click 'Read more'.

Comment: Provided there are long reviews, it would be obvious that game works and it isn't general game problem, but personal bug report. I don't see how "random bug  happened on my single specific PC and I'll give you zero details about reasons" is any more useful than "Great game" listed above. If there are some specific circumstances that always cause problem and thus are useful data, such review will have to name them and thus it won't be short.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to find a few curators that aren't a joke.

Comment: The default review display is "MOST HELPFUL REVIEWS IN THE PAST 30 DAYS". Is that not sufficient for avoiding unhelpful reviews?

Comment: @OrangeDog No. Actually for games used in examples above, "past 30 days" instead of "all time" is even more cluttered with those short non-reviews.

Comment: @l3l_aze Thanks, but I have no desire to be bound to single (or limited amount of) point of view.

Comment: The point being that there is already a built-in system for determining "helpful" and is already available for you to sort by.

Comment: @OrangeDog Do read question CAREFULLY. It is covered there. Voting just doesn't work on those. And that's exactly why I explicitly ask how to filter out short reviews.

Answer (score 4):

### YOU can't. Steam can.

Not even the game company can remove reviews on its own games by themselves. The only one that can remove them is Steam.

To get a review possibly removed, it has to be flagged. To do so, open the rewiev fully, then click the small flag in the lower right corner. This opens a popup where you have to explain **how** the review violates the Steam [Subscriber Agreement](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/english/) and/or [online conduct guidelines](https://store.steampowered.com/online_conduct/). Then it is up to Steam to remove or sustain the review. However, none of those reviews you have picked does violate any of the agreement or code of conduct.

Answer (score 1):

I personally set up a macro for that page, so that when I see a review that isn't helpful, I can activate my mouse-scroll wheel and the page itself will scroll slightly, showing additional reviews at the bottom for me to continue reading. If you activate the macro enough, you keep getting more reviews and the one you didn't like ends up off the top of the screen. It's pretty complicated, but it does it's job. It doesn't get RID of reviews I don't like, mainly because the Steam reviews aren't there for me (or you) personally, but it does help me get past reviews that I don't appreciate.

**Setting up this Macro**

1. You will need a mouse with a scroll wheel.
2. The mouse-wheel/scroll wheel should default bind to "Page Scrolling". If it doesn't, unfortunately, you may have to bind it yourself. This will depend on what browser you're using.
3. Whenever you see a review that is unhelpful or stupid, activate the macro by scrolling your mouse-wheel. What this will do if everything is set up correctly, is cause the page itself to scroll one tick. Sometimes you will have to activate the macro a few times to fully see other reviews, or make the dumb review leave your screen, but it's just a flick of the mouse away with this macro.

Let me know if you have any questions on setting it up, and I'll do what I can to help.